# A normal subgroup of automorphism group

Tags: group-theory

> Let $N$ be characteristic in $G$. The automorphisms $\alpha$ of $G$ satisfying $\alpha\vert_N= 1$ form a normal subgroup of Aut$(G)$.

How to solve this problem? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A=\{\alpha\in {\rm Aut} (G)\mid \alpha\vert_N= 1\}$ be the subset of ${\rm Aut}(G)$ containing all the automorphisms of which the restriction to $N$ is the identity morphism. It's easy to show $A$ is a subgroup of ${\rm Aut}(G)$. Let $\varphi$ be an arbitrary automorphism of $G$, for all $\alpha\in A$, $n\in N$, $n^{\alpha^\varphi}=\varphi^{-1}\alpha\varphi(n)$. Since $N$ is characteristic in $G$, $\varphi(n)\in N$, then $\alpha\varphi(n)=\varphi(n)$. Therefore, $n^{\alpha^\varphi}=\varphi^{-1}\varphi(n)=n,\,\forall n\in N$, so $\alpha^\varphi=1$, i.e., $\alpha^\varphi\in A,\,\forall \varphi\in {\rm Aut}(G)$. Thus, $A\trianglelefteq {\rm Aut}(G)$.